# AlarmManager not working when app process killed

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, alarmmanager

Working with alarm manager I realized that it doesn't work when app process killed but accoriding 
to documentation [They operate outside of your application, so you can use them to trigger events or actions even when your app is not running, and even if the device itself is asleep](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms)
Here is my code:

```
            calendar.timeInMillis = System.currentTimeMillis()
            calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, 1)
            val intent = Intent(applicationContext, ReminderReceiver::class.java)
            val pI =
                PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 65789, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT)
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                AlarmManagerCompat.setExact(am, AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pI)
            }
```

This is in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 <receiver android:name=".RestartServiceReceiver" />
```

My broadcast receiver not calling at all.

Comment: "I realized that it doesn't work when app process killed" -- generally it does, but it depends on your definition of "app process killed" (and, sometimes, on hardware). "My broadcast receiver not calling at all" -- how are you determining this?

Comment: app process killed  means that I remove app from recent and I do log from broadcast receiver to determine that it calls @CommonsWare

Comment: You can use `adb shell dumpsys alarm` to see if your alarm is scheduled. Try running that before and after you remove the app from the overview screen. Also, you might try experimenting with killing your process by other means (e.g., `adb shell am kill ...`, where `...` is your application ID) and see what you get.

Comment: experimenting with code I noticed that when I create java project in android studio this works fine. I have no idea how it works...

Comment: @CommonsWare I tried adb shell dumpsys alarm this shows that my alarm scheduled and it's remain scheduled event after 1 minute.

Comment: The `adb shell dumpsys alarm` output should show you what time your alarm is scheduled for. Is it the value that you expect?

Comment: @CommonsWare Yes. it's value that I expect but alarm not triggering.

Comment: Do any system messages show up in Logcat around the time of your alarm that indicate what is going wrong? If you terminate your process by other means (e.g., `adb shell am kill ...`), what happens?

Comment: No, sorry, `adb shell dumpsys alarm` does not terminate your process. As I noted earlier, `adb shell am kill ...` (where `...` is your application ID) will terminate your process.

Comment: Sorry typo. when I kill app by mean adb shell am kill <appid> alarm work as I not closed app @CommonsWare

Comment: You could try adding an `android:process` attribute to your `<receiver>`, so it runs in another process, and see if that helps. Some device manufacturers are a little too aggressive in what happens when you remove a task.

Comment: I has already tried it. it has no any positive result too @CommonsWare

Comment: This might be one of those badly behaved devices that force closes apps that are swiped away from recents.